# How to exit an app directly when backbutton is pressed?

Tags: android, navigation, onbackpressed

I have 2 activities (A and B) in my app. On activity B I have a custom toolbar.  When the user clicks the toolbar, it will go back to activity A. I want the user to exit the App every time they press the back button on Activity A. 
My problem is every time the user taps the back button on activity A, it will count how many times the user has entered activity B and then exit A.

I'm using this code:

```
toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent goBack=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),seephotoActivity.class);
                goBack.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(goBack);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

I also tried adding `android:noHistory="true"` inside my AndroidManifest.xml but it is still counting. Can someone point out my mistake and EXPLAIN it?

Comment: And what if you just call finish(); without creating goBack Intent() ? It should just return to the "previous" A.

Comment: @Hemix it's still counting

Comment: Oh ok. So maybe I misunderstood your question, sorry

Comment: do you want to exit completely from Activity B without gng to Activity A? where do you take count.?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan i want to exit completely once the user tap backpress on activity A. the counting starts on activity A when the user tap in backpress.

Comment: so you want to like this Activity A --> Activity B ---> Back Press Activity A --> Finish Exit . ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan  i want it like this Activity A --> Activity B ---> Activity A -->  Back Press Activity A --> Finish Exit

Comment: check my answer if it helps you..

Comment: @WilliamAnputra Please click the green check mark next to the answer that best solved your question to [mark the question as answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below code.

**Activity A**

```
// It will navigate to the B Activty. Don't call finish() here.
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class));

// Override the on back press method. 
@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // Process of Counting the no.of views/ counts goes here
      finish();
      super.onBackPressed();
  }
```

**Activity B**

> finish();

call the finish() method, when On pressing the Back in the toolbar.
This will bring back you to the Activity A. Don't start the new activity.

Then when you again press back in ActivityA, it will exit from the App.

Try this, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want exit app try this in activity A

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. So the problem is the activity stacks so what i did was inside Activity B, i override the backpress method like this

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent goback;
        goback = new Intent(B_activity.this, A_Activity.class);
        goback.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        goback.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        startActivity(goback);
    }
```

so when it goes back to Activity A,  activity A will be on top of the stack with nothing else behind activity A.

then inside activity A, i override the backpress method like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        finish();
    }
```

hope it will help those who has same problem as me.